# Must declare the scalar variable with Table-Valued Parameters and Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

Could someone explain why the following gives me "Must declare the scalar variable @facilities." but works fine if I were to use VARCHAR instead of my created type?  How can I fix this?

TIA

```
--CREATE TYPE integer_list AS TABLE (n int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)

--DROP PROCEDURE spTestTVP

CREATE PROCEDURE spTestTVP (
    @facilities integer_list READONLY
    --@facilities varchar(100)
 )
AS
    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000)

    SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM TestTable'

    SET @sql = @sql + ' WHERE 1=1 '

    IF @facilities IS NOT NULL 
        SET @sql = @sql + ' AND (FacilityNo IN (' + @facilities + ') OR FacilityNo IS NULL)'


    EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are concatenating things in a dynamicSQl statment all pieces that build the statement must be either varchar or nvarchar. That is a limit of SQL.

On the other hand you don't need dynamic sql since you have created a table.

```
SELECT * FROM TestTable t
LEFT join @facilities f on f.n = t.facilityNO
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @items VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT@items = COALESCE(@items+',' ,'') + n
FROM @facilities

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000)

    SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM TestTable'

    SET @sql = @sql + ' WHERE 1=1 '

    IF @facilities IS NOT NULL 
        SET @sql = @sql + ' AND (FacilityNo IN (' + @items + ') OR FacilityNo IS NULL)'


    EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

or not dynamic as follows:

```
SELECT t.* FROM TestTable as t
left outer join
@facilities as f
on
 f.n = t.FacilityNo
where
t.FacilityNo is null
or
f.n is not null
```